# Call cloud function from cloud run

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

there is an option to call GCF from GCR?
I created both via terraform and addded policy

GCF

```
data "google_iam_policy" "invoker" {
  binding {
    role = "roles/cloudfunctions.invoker"
    members = var.service_accounts
  }
}

resource "google_cloudfunctions_function_iam_policy" "policy" {
  project = google_cloudfunctions_function.func.project
  region = google_cloudfunctions_function.func.region
  cloud_function = google_cloudfunctions_function.func.name
  policy_data = data.google_iam_policy.invoker.policy_data
}
```

GCR

```
data "google_iam_policy" "invoker" {
  binding {
    role = "roles/run.invoker"
    members = var.service_accounts
  }
}

resource "google_cloud_run_service_iam_policy" "policy" {
  location    = google_cloud_run_service.crun.location
  project     = google_cloud_run_service.crun.project
  service     = google_cloud_run_service.crun.name

  policy_data = data.google_iam_policy.invoker.policy_data
}
```

In the GCR at the coold start, I try call GCF by axios

```
axios.post(this._cloudFunctionUrl as string)
```

When I'm trying to deply it, it crashs with error 403:

```
AxiosError: Request failed with status code 403
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if the runtime service account (of Cloud Functions or Cloud Run, depends on in which you are calling the services) is granted, you need to use the runtime service account to generate a token and to add it to your API Call. that addition is not automatic

Have a look to the [service to service](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service) calls to have samples.